# How to do SFTP access for only one folder/user?

Tags: directory, sftp, restricted-access

I'm using ubuntu 18.
I currently have a folder located in:

```
/home/CS/scriptfiles/Maps/
```

And I want to create a new SFTP user, on port 22, which could ONLY browse the location:

```
/home/CS/scriptfiles/Maps/
```

He should not be able to browse any other folders, or go to the `/home/CS/` directory or even `/home/CS/scriptfiles`. *Only to /home/CS/scriptfiles/Maps/.* He should be able to delete, and upload, edit files there.

How can I make such an user?

Please give an example, I tried searching, but nothing worked.
ALSO.... He should not be able to access SSH (putty). Only this, one folder. via SFTP... For example WinSCP or Filezilla.

Is this even possible?